# Python: How to update only NaN values in pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have got two data frames.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [400, np.nan, 600]})
>>> print(df)
   A      B
0  1  400.0
1  2    NaN
2  3  600.0
```

and

```
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]})
>>> print(new_df)
   B  C
0  4  7
1  5  8
2  6  9
```

How can I update `df` by `new_df` to fill NaN values? I would like to get following:

```
>>> print(df)
   A      B
0  1  400.0
1  2    5.0
2  3  600.0
```

Comment: if the indicies are aligned  you can use `fillna` with `map` is `A` the ID column ?

Comment: ``df.combine_first(new_df).filter(df.columns)``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is using `.update`

```
df.update(new_df, overwrite = False)
df.head()
#output:
    A   B
0   1   400.0
1   2   5.0
2   3   600.0
```

---

## Runtime

```
%%timeit 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3] * 1000, 'B': [400, np.nan, 600] * 1000})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6] * 1000, 'C': [7, 8, 9] * 1000})
df.update(new_df, overwrite = False)
```

> 4.24 ms ± 48.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3] * 1000, 'B': [400, np.nan, 600] * 1000})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6] * 1000, 'C': [7, 8, 9] * 1000})
df.fillna(new_df)
```

> 6.78 ms ± 229 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3] * 1000, 'B': [400, np.nan, 600] * 1000})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6] * 1000, 'C': [7, 8, 9] * 1000})
df['B']  = np.where(df['B'].isnull(), new_df['B'], df['B'])
```

> 3.91 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: I think the 3rd way (np.where) is the most fast because it use numpy method instead of pandas method which need check index first and will cost extra time

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this:

```py
df.fillna(new_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
df['B']  = np.where(df['B'].isnull(), new_df['B'], df['B'])
```

Comment: this is the best(faster) answer and must be accepted +1

Comment: I am sorry I did not accept the answer. It is because my original data frame has got many columns with NaNs and this solution can not be used for the case. However, for toy data I posted, it is brilliant, so I am giving +1.